# WordCloud: the wordcloud.generate(text) function cannot run

Tags: python, word-cloud

When I try to use the `wordcloud.generate(text)` function, I find that cannot run and display a window with information about Python has stopped working. At fist, I think it's a version issue (my WordCloud version is 3.3.3 and python version is 3.8.3 in win7), so I try to use wheel install WordCloud and the version is wordcloud-1.8.1-cp38-cp38-win32.whl. this is my code:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

text = "dog dog cat cat dog"
wordcloud=WordCloud()
wordcloud.generate(text)
```

but when I try to delete `wordcloud.generate(text)`, that can run

Answer (score 0):

When I uninstall my old python and install a new version is 3.7.9_win_amd64, then I try to
restart use `pip install wordcloud`, I find that can run well. I think that must be the old version of python conflicts with my system. The version is win_amd64 and old version of python
is 32-bit.